# Compact Framework development using C# Express Version

Tags: c#, compact-framework, visual-studio-express

I am wondering if one could use the C# Express version to do Compact Framework development. I've done some Google searches but I can't find a defiant answer. I have installed C# Express but there isn't a project template to select for "smart device" development. I will continue my search but I was hoping that the stackoverflow community may be able to assist in finding this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, at least not directly, given that C# Express edition is crippled to only support basic projects and does not allow addins.

Answer (score 3):

To do CF development, you need the runtimes and compiler pieces for it.  Those pieces come with the following:

- Visual Studio 2003 Professional or better
- Visual Studio 2005 Standard or better
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional or better

Microsoft hasn't announced what level of Studio you'll need in version 10 to have Smart Device capabilities (we've been pushing for a low cost or free version).  That said, you can still get into Studio at a fairly low cost with one of the following programs:

- [Empower ISV](https://partner.microsoft.com/40011351)
- [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com)
- [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a third party IDE like ShapDevelop.  The Visual Studio Express Editions do not support Compact Framework, but even with those support can be flaky.

Hmm... based on this link it may have only been working for a couple weeks:
http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=CompactFrameworkDevelopment&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible - even with visual form design. You just have to download .NET CF assemblies to PC, and build project manually, disabling default assemblies and loading the CF ones with /r: command switch.

Use Google, this method is described better in one article.

Best regards -- Spook.